# How to render a variable inside another?

Tags: php

I want to place the variable $all right in the middle of $code, which is HTML code that I gathered from another file. My current code is like this.

```
ob_start();
---code here---
$all = ob_get_clean();
$code = file_get_contents("file.txt");
echo $code;
```

file.txt would look a little something like this.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
---HTML code here---
$all
---More HTML code---
</body>
</html>
```

What should I do so that when I echo $code, $all is rendered inside it?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/messageformatter.formatmessage.php

Comment: do you have a marker that actually identifies where "right in the middle" is? Will $all actually be in the file.txt so you know where to start putting the contents of $all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `str_replace` to replace `$all` with the value.

```
$code = str_replace('$all', $all, $code);
```

Comment: That's so simple, I'm surprised that I didn't think of it before. It works exactly as I want it to now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OP got his solution, but I thought this was worth mentioning as well.

If you don't have a placeholder in the HTML file, but you know that you want to insert `$all` after something specific, you could do something like this:

```
$all = ob_get_clean();
$code = file_get_contents("file.txt");
$after = "<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"something\" />";

$code = substr_replace($code, $all, strpos($code, $after)+strlen($after), 0);
```

This will find `$after` in `$code`, move to the end of it, and then insert `$all`.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use RegEx. 
You could replace 'body' tag by 'body' tag + your var. 
Like :

```
echo preg_replace('/<body>/',"<body>$all",$code);
```

But you have to be sure that one and only one `<body>` tag is present in `$code`

Comment: And the OP will _replace_ `$all` with some content, and not _add_ new `$all` after the body tag. However, regular expressions are even not required. Simple string replacement does exactly the same.